# Mesh transparent in solid mode

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view

I don't know why my object looks transparent even though I have not switched on x-ray in blender
 2.8[image]

in the above image, you could see that the door is translucent. Is there a way to stop this effect?

Comment: Check if the mesh isn't inside out. In overlays in right up corner turn on  face orientation, if it is red check your normals. 
Also that would mean that you have turned on backface culling culling in shading settings.
Another thing can be that the object that is still visible has option "in front" checked

Comment: hey thanks, I had not checked the in front option for the doors.

Comment: hmm, nothing helped? if you can, upload the file.

Comment: it worked, I had tick the in front option for the doors